# I want my Discord bot to send error messages in chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a simple Discord bot with Python and I want it to send an error message(I'm using discord.py 1.7.3), here's the code:

```py
@client.event()
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Something went wrong ¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
        print("{Fore.RED}command didn't work.")
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        ctx.send("Something went wrong ¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
        print("{Fore.RED}command didn't work.")
```

But when I run it, it says this in the Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\User1\Desktop\code> & C:/Users/CSFse/Desktop/stuff/Python/python.exe "c:/Users/User1/Desktop/code/Discord Bot/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User1\Desktop\code\Discord Bot\main.py", line 145, in <module>
    @client.event()
TypeError: Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in the first line you should not use () the correct version is this:

```
@client.event
```

2. in the seventh line you should add await at the start the correct version is:

```
await ctx.send("Something went wrong ¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
```